# Are .net delegates real objects?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been working for some years in C# and one thing always bugs me. Delegates. They have no state, they are pointers to object methods, and the only way to go when dealing with threads or any other type of parallel programming technique that .net has to offer.

My main concern is that when programming in an object oriented style, the fact that delegates break the paradigm by breaking the notion that if you go Object Oriented then the design phase using UML and CRC should map to the language that you use.

So as the title asks, are delegates real objects or a programming anomaly, something that is required to be done outside the scope of Object Oriented Design.

Is it possible therefore for an object to be an object if it has no state and can a delegate be modelled in UML?

A well-known person once gave a public lecture on astronomy. He described how the earth orbits around the sun and how the sun, in turn, orbits around the center of a vast collection of stars called our galaxy. At the end of the lecture, a little old lady at the back of the room got up and said: "What you have told us is rubbish. The world is really a flat plate supported on the back of a giant tortoise." The scientist gave a superior smile before replying, "What is the tortoise standing on?" "You're very clever, young man, very clever", said the old lady. "But it's turtles all the way down! ---- Stephen Hawkins

I think this relates very well to objects and the fundamental types they sit upon. Can you really say its objects all the way down?

Comment: Delegates certainly have state, at least so much as strings and integers have state.

Comment: but a delegate has no state, its just a list of pointers to other object methods. You can add and delete methods to a delegate list which has been encapsulated nicely, but the actual state is changed by the object method, either in its encapsulated state, or as is more frequent in threaded design, an object that has been designed as a DTO.

Comment: @Gabe, we will leave strings for another day :)

Comment: Are you saying that it doesn't have state because it's not mutable? A `Delegate` contains 4 private members and a `MulticastDelegate` inherits those 4 and adds another 2.

Comment: You lost me at "they have no state".  You keep repeating this religiously, but it's a pretty poor religion to put your faith in, since it's demonstrably false.

Comment: If you are familiar with a functor type, then the concept of a delegate should be straightforward.  The state in the functor is (minimally) the method(s) that it invokes as part of its `execute()` method.

Comment: @Ben So far your demonstrations have come to naught. I am still waiting on your updated example you promised me. The only state you have demonstrated so far is a Closure. As Delegates do not allow for Inheritance, public state or any of the other qualifiers to be truly object oriented, I think this is more fails on a Delegate being an object. How would one add more methods to a delegate, to get the values of this state?

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: I lost track of this question for a while.  Now I've added an example both of making state publicly accessible and also polymorphism.  Two things you have to realize: (1) I only ever claimed that delegates have state, I didn't say anything about inheritance, and (2) OOP doesn't always look exactly the same.  Lexical closures are just as valid a mechanism for encapsulation as access modifiers, parametric and type polymorphism are both equally valid, and so on.  If we require prototypes (real OOP languages have that), then not only C# delegates but also C# classes are non-objects

Comment: @Ben Lexical scoping is great, but not OO. Its a fantastic thing and can be used as an alternative to Object thinking. thank you for your input. It has been very constructive.

Comment: I don't use "UML" or "CRC". Am I a bad OO programmer?

Comment: @Matti, No not a bad programmer. Do you explain your designs to non technical people, if so, SOME UML diagrams are a great boon. For example I base my contract and design sign off using Use Cases. Also when dealing with outsourcing contracts I need to make sure that the Diagrams are correct, so when they come up with the implementation, the parts fit the overall design. I wouldn't build a house or a car without designing first, why would I do so with Software?

Comment: @Matti, UML is the language of Object design, and if a company says they use them, then I can explain what I want in diagrams. Delegates are a bug bear of mine, as I always seem to wish I could model them in UML but I end up creating pseudo Classes to describe them or leaving them out of the UML diagrams altogether.

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: You should probably treat delegates as library classes that you did not design.  You can't inherit from `System.String` either, not can you use `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` polymorphically, but this is because some other programmer did the design, not because these OOP principles were not available.  As far as lexical scoping is concerned, I did not say it was OO itself, I said you can use it to build encapsulation which is OO.  Therefore a language doesn't need to have access modifiers to support OOP if it has lexical closures.

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: Similarly you cannot say that delegates are not OO because they do not support inheritance.  **Inheritance is not a principle of OOP**, it is one way of implementing OOP principles of polymorphism and reuse.  Delegates may not have inheritance, but they do support subtype polymorphism and also reuse via composition.  Just because other forms of polymorphism and reuse do not fit into your nice UML world does not mean that they are not OO, it means that UML is not as "universal" as advertised.

Comment: @Ben, inheritance is not a principal of OO, but it does relate to the "Open Closed principal" which is as it says a principal. Yes I am not disputing the usage of Delegates and how and why to use them. I have no problems working with a language that is multi-paradigm which uses basic building blocks that are smaller and more fundamental than objects. I am just trying to classify what a delegate is so that I can treat it correctly in UML. If it is not and object and is as fundamental as it seems to the .Net framework, then simply I will not model it. Thank you once again for your input.

Comment: But OCP (which I called "reuse" in my previous comment) can also be achieved by composition, in fact many computer scientists believe that OCP through composition is superior to OCP through inheritance.  So "delegates don't have inheritance" does not prove that they aren't objects.

Comment: @Ben, yes I agree that composition is far superior to inheritance. But you get different effects from both. When I design code I very much go for composition over inheritance every time. However, I usually do it using interfaces and dependency injection. However, I would not inject an object into a class to "help out" with a little problem of state. It usually involves behaviours or a cross-cutting concern such as logging of external storage. like your style though, nice clear thinking. Composition leads to far more robust solutions.

Answer (score 16):

They're real objects.

When you're modeling with UML it's common to use interfaces.  Do they have state?  No.  Are they any less object-oriented?  Of course not.

Of course a delegate can be modeled in UML.

I think they represent a more functional approach, because they are functions that are first class objects.  That might concern you, but it doesn't detract from the fact that they are indeed objects.

Comment: Interfaces are not objects though, they are design patterns. You implement an interface, making sure that your object adheres to the pattern. How would one model a delegate in UML, could you point me to an example. thanks in advanced.

Comment: I said it was common to use interfaces in UML.  And no, they aren't design patterns.  They are objects with all pure virtual functions.  You'd model a delegate as an object with all the methods in the base class.  You sound like you're really hung up on UML.  It's not a useful obsession.

Comment: Sorry, when I say design pattern I should have made it clear, they are more like patterns of usage not "Design Patterns" in the common sense. You don't implement an interface as an object. What base class, you thinking of Java there, delegates are implemented differently in C#.

Comment: As for my obsession in UML. UML is a programming language, just not been hooked into a code generator as of yet. It will come. When a system fades away into obscurity (Cobol for example), hopefully the schematic diagrams I draw up in UML will still be around to describe in a metaphysical stance of what was analysed and what we tried to achieve. If I modelled a delegate as you stated, it would not be an accurate representation in c# code.

Comment: Interfaces pre-date UML, and they were part of C++ long before there was a Java or C#.  They certainly define types.  With regard to base classes, please see Jon Skeet: a delegate derives from either a Delegate or a MulticastDelegate.  There are inherited methods, whether you know or use them.

Comment: UML is *not* a programming language.  Cobol has not faded into obscurity.  It's running all over the world right now.  As for your UML diagrams, they'll be sitting on shared drives, ignored by all those organizations that are still happily running systems developed with real programming languages.  You fail to understand UML, objects, or delegates.

Comment: Cobol is fading into obscurity, nearly all the organizations I have worked with in the last couple of years are moving systems over to modern languages. The only exception I have come across in the UK is a large catalogue company called Argos. What is your problem with UML, you don't think that its relevant?

Comment: Cobol will still be running banks when you and I are retired.  It's been fading into obscurity for 20 years.  Is UML relevant?  Absolutely not.  It's fading into obscurity a lot faster than Cobol.

Comment: Stateless objects are still objects.  You seem to have odd ideas about what is and is not an object.

Comment: Not many banks in the UK running AS400's these days :). And German banks are moving over to functional programming in a big way. I don't see many graduates moving into Cobol, When I left in '97 I was kitted up in Java and Delphi and UML. You got to move with the times, UML is being used heavily out there, the Agents are all marketing themselves as "Agile" not having a clue what it means!, thing is though with languages like python making nice inroads into the mainstream, and all that dreaded interpreted stuff, you need some good designs to keep the code in check.

Comment: Odd Ideas? whats the point of a stateless object? may as well drop OO and go functional/procedural if you think that way. Hey just put all your methods in one big object, make a couple of objects that hold the state, and pass the one object into the other objects methods, thats objects ain't it ;)?

Comment: I agree that not many graduates are moving into Cobol, but that doesn't mean no one is running those older systems.  Unless you've worked at a significant number of companies in the UK and Germany and can back up the statement with some data, I'd say you're speculating.  I'm basing my view on personal experience at three companies that are part of the Dow Jones in the US and a fourth smaller one that manufactures helicopters.  I know UML well.  See Fowler: I'm firmly in the "sketchers" camp.  MDA is a failure.  http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ModelDrivenArchitecture.html

Comment: Like I said, stateless objects are objects nonetheless. You need to learn a bit more, I'm afraid.

Comment: Most people I talk too, are currently afraid of the cost of keeping systems on that can not be maintained. I used to do Cobol, so I can't knock the language, made a bit of money in 1999 with a few companies, some I worked with said enough was enough and killed the Cobol off replacing it quick speed with terrible designed software in the latest fad language (I think it was COM+, horrible!). Which companies you work for, genuinely interested. I been around the block a bit, banks, insurance, start-ups, not fussed as long as they pay :)

Comment: I've had two careers: one as a mechanical engineer, another as a software developer, mostly with financial service and insurance firms.  I'd say that Microsoft and Jon Skeet would both say that delegates are first-class objects.  I'd certainly consider both of them more authoritative than me.  Based on the evidence, I agree with them.

Comment: Maybe an object duffy, but thats piss poor design if you think that an object can get away with just having methods, or members :)

Comment: Object Cobol, that cracks me up.

Comment: Go tell Jon Skeet that he's a piss poor designer.  Do you know who he is?

Comment: Object Cobol?  Where did you see that?  Or is that just another topic you're bringing in?

Comment: I think you need to learn a lot more about objects.  Your view of what is and is not an object is very narrow, indeed.

Comment: I done my learning about objects. If you start thinking in a decoupled way that your on the verge of, you may was well throw it away. I'm not saying that separating of data from functions is a bad idea, just that it goes against design principals of Object Design. Your data becomes scoped by using a container object, but that object may as well be a basic array. Maybe the Lisp and Schemers were right all along, maybe objects never worked. heck a program is just tree structure, how stupid am I, wasting all these years on objects :)

Comment: @duffymo: +1 for the trouble. :)

Comment: If you were paying attention, you'd see that the Lisp and Schemers are no less correct than they've always been.  Haven't you noticed what's happening with functional programming?  Scala, Erlang, F#?  Objects aren't anything special; they're just another attempt to manage complexity.  A program *is* just an abstract tree structure.

Comment: Philosophically speaking, objects are very special and exist outside of the domain of programming. Yes I agree inside of code Objects are nothing special. Where objects come into their own is when speaking to real people (not pogrammers) and trying to convey meaning to their world in a visual format. Most projects I work on, I need to prove that the work I am doing has some value, no Director wants to see lines of code, but diagrams, they can't get enough of. Only problem with Object Design, is that you must carry it through to your code, to work with others, because the parts must fit.

Comment: As for the functional languages, I think that's outside of the scope of this discussion, personally I love them, but then again I like the maths. Lisp and Schemers I feel have the pulse at the moment. No BS in a lisp program, you look at it, you head hurts, but the structures are raw and unsugared and very much closer to AST's than anything I have seen thus far. Just a bugger to work with :)

Comment: Your views on objects reflects more upon your understanding of objects than it does on objects themselves.  You've made up your mind what objects are, and it's frankly a relatively shallow understanding.  You may wish to research the Actor model, and consider objects-as-Actors as a design paradigm.  In such a model, objects would *never* have publicly accessible state since there's no concept of 'return values' in the Actor model (at least, between Actors).  Consider as well that some developers consider getters and setters to break encapsulation, and be poor OO design.

Comment: @Kyroryu yeah yeah we all read the David West Book (Object Thinking, on sale now at all good MS retailers), but don't confuse the Design stuff to the implementation. This is about Delegates.

Answer (score 7):

It's become clear that this point isn't going to get across without somebody wielding the closure hammer.  No, not the "close this question" hammer.

```
Action @ICanHazState()
{
    int callcount = 0;
    Action retval = delegate {
       System.MessageBox("I haz bin calld " + callcount.ToString() + " tims b4");
       if (++callcount > 5) throw new InvalidOperationException("Call limit exceeded.  Kaboom!");
    };
    return retval;
}
```

[Complete compilable example here](http://ideone.com/PhgRt)

[More complex example (requires C# 4 e.g. Visual Studio 2010)](http://ideone.com/I2oY6)

Comment: I think your hammer would be more effective if you show the output of a small program using the closure.

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: It's just a little delegate wanting to show that **it has state**.

Comment: what happens when @ICanHazeState() goes out of scope, doesn't callCount get wiped out?

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: Click the link to the example, observe the behavior.

Comment: WeNeedAnswers: Every time you call `ICanHazState`, a new `callCount` gets created, entirely separate from all the other ones that have been created.

Comment: Well, in the end the variable is hoisted into a helper class.  But you wouldn't say that a `List<T>` doesn't have content just because it uses a helper object (array) to hold its content.  Here the state is held in a helper object as well, but as soon as `ICanHazState` returns the delegate has sole ownership of the state object, so I'd definitely say the "the state belongs to the delegate".  And as far as the C# language and you, the programmer, are concerned, that local variable was *captured by the delegate*.

Comment: In a helper object used by the delegate to store state.

Comment: I love that this answer destroys the obvious pro dynamic languages flame bait the OP tried.

Comment: +1 (+10 if I could) for very witty example ("Kitteh sad" had me in fits)

Comment: Can you access the Helper Object outside of the scope of the delegate? Can you change the scope of the local variable? If none of this is valid, then sorry its not OOP, its something else, and proves to me that its not Object thinking at all.

Comment: Can you show me an example that doesn't rely on the magic that is Console :)

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: The helper object can only be accessed by the delegate itself, and the method that initializes it (`ICanHazState`).  I don't see how you claim this means it is not OOP, since *encapsulation* is one of the fundamental principles of OOP.  It's possible to share objects with the delegate of course, using references.  Maybe I'll work up an example later.

Comment: thanks. Yes I understand the mechanics of it. So your saying to get the magic to work you would have to pass in a reference into the delegate which is stored outside of the delgate to get at the insides of the delegate. I think this breaks the open/closed principal of OO. The State of the delegate is only accessible by passing in a ref of another object, thus the external object becomes the state object. Don't get me wrong, I loved the example, and will use it, I got some python code that will move across with the technique above, but for argument sake its not true OO.

Comment: The complex example? Does that compile? Thanks for your efforts with the coding, its really cool that you do that. Just need to look at it in depth before I comment though :)

Comment: Nice example, but do you really think that passing in an out parameter (another object) proves that the delegate is an object, or a workaround for the fact that a delegate isn't an object and this is the only way to get at its internals?

Comment: The complex example needs C# 4, it will not compile in the version of mono used on ideone.  Was that not clear from my post?  Also, in case you didn't notice, those out parameters, which you called objects, are also delegates.  I think that means I win.

Comment: @Ben ha ha. you win indeed , I think not :). Just because it is classed as a first class type, does not mean its an object. Nice try. In functional programming as you jolly well know, you pass functions round as standard. But in a functional language I wouldn't dare mention the Class word, they would kill me for being a half breed impure ;) Unless your saying that function declarations in say Haskell are really objects? If so its a different way of thinking about functions than the functional world might think. It would change the functional paradigm on its head. thanks once again.

Comment: I'm saying that objects don't need to be based on a class model (which is a prerequisite for inheritance).  And yes, Haskell functions have everything necessary to make objects.  Read http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ralf/OOHaskell/

Comment: Nice thinking there, I will have to give it more thought. Its something I have not looked at. Give me a day and will get back to you on this. Its an interesting concept of objects without hierarchy. I think your on to something there. Will also read the pdf link. thanks. Sounds a lot like dynamic programming in the style of JavaScript prototyping as opposed to python. I am a heavy user of interfaces, maybe this is a way to go. I got a feeling though its moving into functional programming where they call classes something else. Sounds like functional Composition.

Comment: maybe I should scrap UML and go back to SSADM :)

Comment: Quick question, how far do you think you can take this using delegates as objects, a whole program written from start to finish? There must be some overhead if you tried this in C#, I know that this is what f# does, not too sure on the .net types used are in f# declarations. You got my head buzzing now, thanks.

Comment: I think I found my answer to the above. It will blow the stack space :)

Comment: Can you imagine say 200 delegates on the stack representing say a person. Heavens forbid all those addresses. And don't get me started on those damn orders and orderlines. :)

Comment: Well, delegates should be very effective in continuation-passing style, which requires tail calls to avoid exhausting the stack.  I don't know if you can convince the C# compiler to generate tail calls to delegates.  Eric Lippert, one of the C# designers, wrote about CPS recently [part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/21/continuation-passing-style-revisited-part-one.aspx), [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/22/continuation-passing-style-revisited-part-two-handwaving-about-control-flow.aspx).

Comment: Yes Ben, tail recursion would solve this, but you may as well go functional f#. Only problem I have with that is that I like the ease of modelling you get with OOP over FOP of business domains. Would it lead to abuse?

Comment: Nice articles on CPS. Had a quick browse, will look at them more in depth.

Answer (score 3):

From wikipedia ([Object (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29): In the domain of object-oriented programming an object is usually taken to mean a compilation of attributes (object elements) and behaviors (methods or subroutines) encapsulating an entity.  Delegates all are subclassed from the Delegate class in .Net.  The Delegate class certainly has attributes (i.e. properties): Method & Target.  The class also has behaviors (methods): Combine, CreateDelegate among others.

Delegates are **not** pointers, as a simple pointer to a method could not encapsulate the 'this' pointer, which delegates do.  As Gabe pointed out, delegates also have state, they could be empty (in which case invoking them does nothing) or they could have one or more methods in their list.

Having satisfied the criteria for an object, they are objects.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Who's Gabe?  None of the folks responding here go by that tag.  Wait, now I see - first comment.

Comment: could you explain that bit about 'this'?

Comment: WeNeedAnswers: When you call a method like `employee.GetSalary()`, the `GetSalary` method gets called with the value of `employee` as an invisible first parameter. Inside of the `GetSalary` method, you access that parameter with the keyword `this`. When you create a delegate for `employee.GetSalary`, it creates an object with both a pointer to the `GetSalary` method and the value for `employee`.

Comment: Creates or Calls, I thought that it just calls the method on the already created object on the current thread that its operating on. Where does the 'this' come into it, I thought that would be a given, given that the object being called knows exactly the context to which it is being called in and in which scope.

Comment: WeNeedAnswers: *Creating* a delegate *creates* an object holding a function pointer and a parameter. *Calling* that delegate *calls* that function pointer with the included parameter.

Comment: WeNeedAnswers: the code for the method is loaded into memory once, no matter how many instances of the class are created, therefore the way the code in the method understands the context is with the hidden parameter that is a reference to the instance, you access this reference with the 'this' keyword.

Comment: Oh I get where your coming from, I was thinking elsewhere, thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They don't break the object oriented paradigm. They just embrace and extend it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Define "object."

Your definition seems to be that to be an object, 'thing' must have *mutable* state and be inheritable.

By that definition, delegates are not objects.  However, I consider that definition to be extremely, extremely limited.  Entire categories of 'objects' in real-world applications fail by that definition.  Functors, to start with.  Many decorator types would also fail by that definition, as well as things like filter objects.

If you go back to Smalltalk, for instance, both `true` and `false` are objects.  By your definition, they would not be.

Comment: Exactly right.  Java enums wouldn't qualify as objects either, yet they inherit from Enum.  The JVM certainly sees them as objects.

Comment: Same with C#; no different.  http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson17.aspx

Comment: Is a string an Object, now come on, be honest, you think that a string is really not an array of chars in disguise. Enums, sugar syntax for a read only associative array?

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers:  Fine, then, as I said in my answer - define "object."

Comment: @kyoryu, I think if you can duplicate something in a language using the constructs of the language, including the syntax sugar that the syntax of the language uses, then I would say that this is an object. From that definition, if you can not duplicate the functionality, the syntax sugar or replace of such article in code then this is not an object. Under this definition, a String, an Enum and a delegate are not objects. As for objects outside of the language specifics, take a look at the OMG's definition, or take a look at the marvellous David Wests book on Object Thinking.